# Change images depending on tvOS Dark Mode or Light Mode?

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos

Exactly what the title says, I would like to change an image on tvOS 12 depending on if its in Dark mode or Light mode. I looked all over the internet to find nothing on this. Only thing I can find is for MacOS not tvOS. Any help is much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to key off of `UIUserInterfaceStyle` value.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiuserinterfacestyle